# gpioset: error setting the GPIO line values: Device or resource busy

Tags: embedded-linux, pin

I am using Linux on my SAMA5D27 embedded board. I am also using libgpiod to manipulate GPIO configurations of the board. First, I can list all the lines of specified gpiochips, their names, consumers, direction, active state with `gpioinfo` command, and this shows me:

```
gpiochip0 - 128 lines:
        line   0:        "PA0"       unused   input  active-high 
        line   1:        "PA1"       unused   input  active-high 
        line   2:        "PA2"       unused   input  active-high 
        line   3:        "PA3"       unused   input  active-high 
        line   4:        "PA4"       unused   input  active-high 
        line   5:        "PA5"       unused   input  active-high 
        line   6:        "PA6"       unused   input  active-high 
        line   7:        "PA7"       unused   input  active-high 
        line   8:        "PA8"       unused   input  active-high 
        line   9:        "PA9"       unused   input  active-high 
        line  10:       "PA10"        "red"  output  active-high [used]
        line  11:       "PA11"       unused   input  active-high 
...
```

For my work, I want to reserve "PA10" for personal us;, this pin refers to a red LED. But whatever command used to manipulate this GPIO pin it shows me:

```
error setting the GPIO line values: Device or resource busy
```

I think that is because it's shown as `[used]`.

Is there a way to make it unused? To make it free so I can manipulate it?

Answer (score 0):

The `used` marker and `Device or resource busy` mean that this I/O pin has been claimed for exclusive use by a driver.

There are a few ways to dig into what might be using the pin:

- Check `/sys/class/gpio/gpio*/` (now deprecated, but often still used)
- Check `/sys/kernel/debug/gpio` (if you have `debugfs` available and mounted)
- Review your active device tree, to see if the pin is associated with a device or driver

It's named `red` here, and you mentioned it's an LED, so it could be exposed under `/sys/class/leds/*`, possibly with a default trigger? If so, you can re-purpose it by modifying the trigger, or unregister it as an LED if you want to manually control the pin more directly / with libgpiod... editing the device tree would probably be the way to make the change permanent.

Answer (score -1):

"Used" means that this pin is connected to a peripheral device or a bus. You can check from kernel device tree dts file and board schematic to see which one is mapped to this pin. Eg, if pin is connected to i2c bus, you shall use i2c command instead of gpio cmd.